# JVM Crashes while 25000 clients are accessing remote kaa Server resource

Tags: oracle, jvm, kaa

I run 25000 clients that just upload log to server every 1 second. The Server crashes in the process.From the log file, we found that the cause of the crash was the JVM crash.The Error log show :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f032964f085, pid=2043, tid=0x00007f02955cd700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5c4085]  G1ParScanThreadState::copy_to_survivor_space(InCSetState, oopDesc*, markOopDesc*)+0x45
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid2043.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

My JVM Arguments and System and [more infos](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=zh#!searchin/kaaproject/JVM$20Crashes$20while$2025000$20clients$20are$20accessing$20remote$20kaa$20Server$20resource%7Csort:relevance/kaaproject/ymZJZJBdOd0/OhpsTRsYBQAJ) :

```
    VM Arguments:
    jvm_args: -Xms256M -Xmx16G -XX:+UseG1GC -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dserver_log_dir=/var/log/kaa -Dserver_log_sufix= -Dserver_home_dir=/usr/lib/kaa-node -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
    java_command: org.kaaproject.kaa.server.node.KaaNodeApplication
    java_class_path (initial): /usr/lib/kaa-node/conf:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/curator-client-2.9.0.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/fastutil-6.5.7.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/application-action-0.0.64.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/joda-time-2.2.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/httpcore-4.3.2.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/velocity-1.7.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/jetty-http-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/gwt-client-0.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/swagger-annotations-1.5.9.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/core-0.10.0.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/jetty-security-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/commons-compress-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/netty-codec-4.0.34.Final.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/dao-0.10.0.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/file-appender-0.10.0.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/gwtquery-1.4.2.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/facebook-verifier-0.10.0.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/transport-0.10.0-tcp.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/spring-data-mongodb-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/cassandra-driver-extras-3.0.0.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/cassandra-all-3.4.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/ant-launcher-1.9.4.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/guava-18.0.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/kaa-node-0.10
    Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

    Environment Variables:
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
    SHELL=/bin/bash
SYSTEM:
    OS:DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"

    uname:Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64
    libc:glibc 2.19 NPTL 2.19 
    rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 32768, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
    load average:23.81 21.57 24.39

    /proc/meminfo:
    MemTotal:       32629180 kB
    MemFree:        11245384 kB
    MemAvailable:   16204112 kB
    Buffers:          116504 kB
    Cached:          5084432 kB
    SwapCached:            0 kB
    Active:          9205152 kB
    Inactive:        3234744 kB
    Active(anon):    7260192 kB
    Inactive(anon):     1048 kB
    Active(file):    1944960 kB
    Inactive(file):  3233696 kB
    Unevictable:     8523068 kB
    Mlocked:         8523068 kB
    SwapTotal:             0 kB
    SwapFree:              0 kB
    Dirty:              3096 kB
    Writeback:             0 kB
    AnonPages:      15762160 kB
    Mapped:           168560 kB
    Shmem:              1384 kB
    Slab:             280612 kB
    SReclaimable:     181816 kB
    SUnreclaim:        98796 kB
    KernelStack:       17856 kB
    PageTables:        36468 kB
    NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
    Bounce:                0 kB
    WritebackTmp:          0 kB
    CommitLimit:    16314588 kB
    Committed_AS:   18242600 kB
    VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
    VmallocUsed:           0 kB
    VmallocChunk:          0 kB
    HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
    AnonHugePages:  15398912 kB
    CmaTotal:              0 kB
    CmaFree:               0 kB
    HugePages_Total:       0
    HugePages_Free:        0
    HugePages_Rsvd:        0
    HugePages_Surp:        0
    Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
    DirectMap4k:       70872 kB
    DirectMap2M:     2754560 kB
    DirectMap1G:    30408704 kB


    CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

    /proc/cpuinfo:
    processor   : 0
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 60
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    stepping    : 3
    microcode   : 0x1d
    cpu MHz     : 3800.109
    cache size  : 8192 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 8
    core id     : 0
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 0
    initial apicid  : 0
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 7183.28
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 1
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 60
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    stepping    : 3
    microcode   : 0x1d
    cpu MHz     : 3860.859
    cache size  : 8192 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 8
    core id     : 1
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 2
    initial apicid  : 2
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 7183.28
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 2
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 60
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    stepping    : 3
    microcode   : 0x1d
    cpu MHz     : 3799.968
    cache size  : 8192 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 8
    core id     : 2
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 4
    initial apicid  : 4
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 7183.28
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 3
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 60
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    stepping    : 3
    microcode   : 0x1d
    cpu MHz     : 3799.968
    cache size  : 8192 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 8
    core id     : 3
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 6
    initial apicid  : 6
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 7183.28
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 4
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 60
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    stepping    : 3
    microcode   : 0x1d
    cpu MHz     : 3893.906
    cache size  : 8192 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 8
    core id     : 0
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 1
    initial apicid  : 1
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 7183.28
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 5
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 60
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    stepping    : 3
    microcode   : 0x1d
    cpu MHz     : 3800.109
    cache size  : 8192 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 8
    core id     : 1
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 3
    initial apicid  : 3
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 7183.28
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 6
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 60
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    stepping    : 3
    microcode   : 0x1d
    cpu MHz     : 3799.968
    cache size  : 8192 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 8
    core id     : 2
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 5
    initial apicid  : 5
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 7183.28
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 7
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 60
    model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    stepping    : 3
    microcode   : 0x1d
    cpu MHz     : 3799.968
    cache size  : 8192 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 8
    core id     : 3
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 7
    initial apicid  : 7
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 7183.28
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:



    Memory: 4k page, physical 32629180k(11245384k free), swap 0k(0k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_111-b14), built on Sep 22 2016 16:14:03 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

    time: Fri Nov 25 05:01:22 2016
    elapsed time: 21112 seconds (0d 5h 51m 52s)
```

In my limited experience with JVM. So I am searching for a long time on net and find related errors at [Oracle site](https://search.oracle.com/search/search?start=1&search_p_main_operator=all&q=G1ParScanThreadState%3A%3Acopy_to_survivor_space&group=bugs.java.com).But I didn't find a solution from it. From my error log:

> Memory: 4k page, physical 32629180k(11245384k free), swap 0k(0k free)

show the physical memory occupied too much.This can be caused by any bug that corrupts heap memory. It could be an issue with GC, with the compiler, with bad native code.

Comment: you did not provide enough info. what activity is done on server side? how big is log file? if 25000 users upload 1MB, then you have 25GB that do not fit in memory.

Comment: The more infos in the link "more infos" above .the log file is not big, just 0.5KB .I think it is not a reason.

Comment: You have `MemFree:        11245384 k` so I doubt you have run out of memory. More likely you have either hit a bug in the G1 collector, or you have corrupted the memory in native code (if you have any).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use any native libraries that might have corrupted the heap, this a a bug in the JVM. You should check whether Oracle already knows about the bug and (if not) file a bug report.

The name of the problematic frame (`G1ParScanThreadState::copy_to_survivor_space`) strongly suggest that the garbage collector (GC) crashes. So for a workaround until the bug is fixed you can try any of the following:

- Monitor the garbage collector and make sure the memory usage doesn't increase over time and the garbage collector doesn't use too much CPU time
- Change the garbage collector parameters (see [Java's command line
  parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html))
- Switch to a different garbage collector (see [Java's command line parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html))

As you're trying to work around a bug, it's trial and error.